# Give an example of a cover for $\Bbb R$ (with the standard topology) that’s infinite, but locally finite.

Tags: general-topology

> A collection $\{A_j\}_{j \in J}$ of subsets of a topological space $X$ is locally finite if for every $x \in X$, there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ for which $U_x \cap A_j \ne \emptyset$ for finitely many $j$. Give an example of an cover for $\Bbb R$ (with the standard topology) that’s infinite, but locally finite.

I’m not sure if I understand what they’re asking here. It seems that they want me to construct some cover $\{A_j\}$ for which $\Bbb R \subset \bigcup_{j} A_j$ and now for every $x \in \Bbb R$ I should be able to find a neighborhood $U_x$ for which $U_x$ meets $A_j$ for $j \in \{1, \dots n\}$? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of the opposite. They want a cover that every point has a neighborhood that only intersects with finitely many elements of your cover.   For $\mathbb{R}$,  this is pretty trivial,  just take any cover of overlapping intervals that only overlap with one other interval on either side.   For instance,  take intervals of width 1, moving back and forth every .5,   so intervals of the form $(.5n,.5n+1), n\in \mathbb{Z}$.   You can see that any point in the reals has an open neighborhood that only intersects at most 2 of these.

Answer (score 1):

Take, for instance $\{(n-1,n+1)\mid n\in\Bbb Z\}$. Can you show that it is locally finite?

Comment: Okay, width 2 marching by 1s is simpler than width 1 marching by 1/2s :)

Comment: @Alan It's simpler to write, but it's the same idea.

Comment: Picking $x \in \Bbb R$ I have that any nbhd $U_x$ meets some of the elements of the cover you described. Intuitively it seems that there is only couple of intervals that meet $U_x$, but I am not sure how to argue this mathematically.

Comment: @JimingLe Specify the radius of a ball around $x$ that's small enough to get you the result you want.  For any $x$ you only need to find one suitable neighborhood so just construct a neighborhood $U_x$ that works.

Comment: Wouldn’t $(x-\frac12, x+ \frac12)$ work just fine? It seems to me that pretty much any $(x-\varepsilon, x+\varepsilon)$ would work?

Comment: Yes, any open interval centered at $x$ will work.